# Delete multiple records with different identifiers from a large table without using loop mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb, sql-delete

I have a million rows table. I need to delete all the rows that have a certain column equal to one of values from 15k long list.

Right now I have it setup as:

```
$list = array(
"Item1",
...
"Item15000"
);

foreach ($list as $item){

$sql = "Delete from table where `item`='$item'";

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "$item removed from table <br>";
        } else {
            echo "Error removing $item from shop_meta: " . $con->error . "<br>";
        }

}
```

In its current state it takes many many hours to do it, and I have to do it for many other similar tables as well.

How do I speed it up or optimize the query? Is there a way to query them all at once to get it done faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put those 15k list in a table and then join against it

```
Delete t
from your_table t
join temp_table tt on t.item = tt.delete_value
```

Comment: does a temp table should only have a single column `delete_value` in it?

Comment: Yes, it does not need more. If you  already have those values in the DB then you can join whereever they are in the DB

Comment: Ahh, this is perfect, and IN FACT I already have a table with a list of items I need to filter out! Thanks so much, master!

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:

```
DELETE FROM t WHERE item IN (...long list of ids...)
```

Plan B:

Do plan A, but in chunks of 1000 ids.  This will be friendlier to other users and replication (if relevant).  Suggest running with `autocommit=ON`.

[*More tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig) on big deletes.